# Walking a number of kilometers in one direction in digital map

Tags: geojson, geometry, turf

Is there a recommended way to calculate the new position of a point in a map when "moving" the point for example 10 kilometers to south ?

Example:

```
Point = {
    lat : 'LATITUDE VALUE',
    lng : 'LONGITUDE VALUE'
}
```

Now we want to get the new Position of the Point when the Point is moving like this:

```
Point_2 = movePoint(Point, 10, 'kilometers', 'south'); // returns lat,lng
```

Now I am looking for a recommended way to calculate something like this or maybe with a framework like turfjs (I think turfjs is not providing this ?)

Comment: Thanks for marking the question! I did not found this post before :) It should help! Thanks.